# Trying to use Row over by partition to group data

Tags: sql-server-2014, partition

I am trying to get the number of stores per week that had zero sales on products but I am doing something wrong with the row over by partition function.

This is my code:

```
    IF object_id('tempdb..#All', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #All;
    IF object_id('tempdb..#Zeros', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Zeros;

     Select distinct [FiscalYr]
          ,[FiscalWk]
          ,[Store]
          ,[UPCCode]
          ,[ItemSku]
          ,[SumUnits]
          ,[SumSales]
          ,[ProdCatg]
          ,Description=Descripton
            into #All 
      FROM [Scans].[dbo].[Scans] s
      left outer join [Tableau].[dbo].[Umpqua_Dairy_Authorizations] a 
      on s.UPCCode= a.[UPC] 
      where FiscalYr = '2015' 
      and
      Descripton = a.Descripton



      SELECT * ,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPCCode ORDER BY FiscalWk) RN 
      FROM #All
      where SumSales = 0
      group by UPCCode,[FiscalYr]
          ,[FiscalWk]
          ,[Store]
          ,[ItemSku]
          ,[SumUnits]
          ,[SumSales]
          ,[ProdCatg]
          ,Description
```

Right now it is counting the rows per UPCCode, so the first UPC has rows 1-7 and the second one has Rows 1-5. What I want it to look like is this:

FiscalWk  UPCCode        #StoresZeroSales
2          48500017753       7
3          48500017753       5

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `ROW_NUMBER` at all, this is a simple `COUNT`:

```
SELECT  FiscalWk,
        UPCCode,
        COUNT(*) [#StoresZeroSales]
FROM #All
WHERE SumSales = 0
GROUP BY FiscalWk,
         UPCCode;
```